# change URL parameter in Codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter, url

I'm trying to change the URL parameter from the row ID to the NAME of the article. here is my code

Controllers

```
public function view($id=0)
{
    if( !isset($id) || !is_numeric($id) ) {
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    $tot = $this->Model_service->service_check($id);
    if(!$tot) {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
```

and the view is

```
        <?php
        foreach ($services as $row) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="services-item effect-item">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>service/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" class="image-effect">
                        <div class="services-photo" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/uploads/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>)"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="services-text">
                        <h3><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>service/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></h3>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo nl2br($row['short_description']); ?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="button-bn">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>service/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo READ_MORE; ?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
```

please help me with the most simplified answer thank you

Comment: for example the website now shows :    example.com/service/view/1 (ID) what i need is example.com/service/NAME of the article

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to change your article view function in controller. Lookup article name instead of id. But name might contains spaces which is not URL friendly so using concept of slug will solve this.

```
public function view($slug='')
{
if($slug == '') {
    redirect(base_url());
}

$tot = $this->Model_service->find_service_by_slug($slug);
if(!$tot) {
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

Reference link for concept of slug is https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html